# Bypass ESLint's `no-unused-var` for Should in a Mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, lint, should.js, eslint

I'm using ESLint on all my files, including the test files, with a `no-unused-var: true` rule. I'm using Should.js in my Mocha tests, and in one of the files, I'm getting an error on the `should` variable. A quick comparison to the other tests shows, that in other files I have at least one line that starts with `should` (i.e. `should.not.exist(err);`), whereas in this particular file, I only use it in property form (i.e. `a.should.equal(b)`).

Short of turning the rule off for the entire file, or coercing perfectly readable tests into the variable use of `should`, is there any way around this? Can I turn off the rule just for the `should` variable? Perhaps add an exception for it? Or (hopefully) a more elegant solution?

Comment: As i know there is no way for eslint to disable it for should.js only and i do not think you need to make something for this. Such linter violations happen because one of lines contains assertion with only getters like `a.should.be.true` will violate. There is pending PR in https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/pull/64, which i am trying to address by next 2 weeks. So tl;dr just do not use getters for now, but only function equivalents (like .true -> .equal(true), less readable, but without violations).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, doesn't seem like there's an elegant solution to this, but I think I came up with a close approximation: I just added a single line to my `before()` hook, stating simply `should;`. Since this evaluates to the should object, or in other words a "truthy" value, it can be treated as a no-op. The side effect is that now the `should` variable is "used", and ESLint does not throw a warning.

I'm going to let this answer hang for a while, hoping one of you has a better solution.

Per request, here's [a gist showing the hack in action](https://gist.github.com/TravelingTechGuy/d1304e957bdee37b8239).

Comment: Could you post gist of you test, where you use getters and that trick helps with eslint? I would like to add it to faq.

Comment: @denbardadym added gist per request - tests are obviously obfuscated, but I think the idea is preserved.

Comment: You can use the option `"varsIgnorePattern": "^should$"`.

Comment: Also, you can use the following syntax too `should(body).have.property('link')`

Comment: Ha! Just commented on you gist which is same as the answer above! Found this SO question afterwards!

Answer (score 12):

In this particular file you can just require instead of declaring.

```
var should = require('should');
```

instead do

```
require('should');
```